# Lucene - how to get all child docs in a parent's block given a parent docID

Tags: lucene

I am using straight up Lucene (no Solr or ElasticSearch) to index a set of documents of which follow a parent-child hierarchy.

I am using 'blocks' to accomplish this by adding all children followed by the parent to the same block calling:

```
writer.addDocuments(childrenAndParentDocList)
```

I am doing a free text search across all parents and children (using ToParentBlockJoinQuery in the child search to link up to the parent docs), which is returning a nice set of parent Documents that either match the query, or which have a child which matches the query.

The next thing I need to do is to fetch *all* children for *all* of the parent documents that I have.

I have seen a method in a lucene test [here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/join/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/join/TestBlockJoin.java), which shows how to get the parent doc, given a child doc.

```
  private Document getParentDoc(IndexReader reader, BitSetProducer parents, int childDocID) throws IOException {
    final List<LeafReaderContext> leaves = reader.leaves();
    final int subIndex = ReaderUtil.subIndex(childDocID, leaves);
    final LeafReaderContext leaf = leaves.get(subIndex);
    final BitSet bits = parents.getBitSet(leaf);
    return leaf.reader().document(bits.nextSetBit(childDocID - leaf.docBase));
  }
```

But I'm unsure of how to do the opposite.  i.e. how to fetch all children given a parent doc.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is about getting all children before one parent document. This is equal to getting the previous parent. So most possible you are looking for this funktion:
org.apache.lucene.util.BitSet.prevSetBit(int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've ended up using the code below.  And it seems to work:

```
private List<Integer> getChildDocIds(IndexSearcher indexSearcher, int parentDocId) throws IOException {
    //Use a query in QueryBitSetProducer constructor which identifies parent docs
    BitSetProducer parentsFilter = new QueryBitSetProducer(new TermQuery(new Term("child", "N")));
    IndexReader indexReader = indexSearcher.getIndexReader();
    List<LeafReaderContext> leaves = indexReader.leaves();
    int subIndex = ReaderUtil.subIndex(parentDocId, leaves);
    LeafReaderContext leaf = leaves.get(subIndex);
    int localParentDocId = parentDocId - leaf.docBase;
    List<Integer> childDocs = new ArrayList<>();
    if (localParentDocId == 0) { 
        //not a parent, or parent has no children
        return childDocs;
    }
    int prevParent = parentsFilter.getBitSet(leaf).prevSetBit(localParentDocId - 1);
    for(int childDocIndex = prevParent + 1; childDocIndex < localParentDocId; childDocIndex++) {
        childDocs.add(leaf.docBase + childDocIndex);
    }
    return childDocs;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. For others: If you don't have `QueryBitSetProducer` available maybe use `FixedBitSetCachingWrapperFilter` and then use `var bitSet = (FixedBitSet)parents.GetDocIdSet(leaf, null)`, where parents is your `FixedBitSetCachingWrapperFilter`. Obviously store the caching wrapper and re-use across queries.

Answer (score -1):

Base on your answer I made a c# port of the function, it also seems to work.

I only needed to get the nested documents without any filters or quires.

```
private List<Lucene.Net.Documents.Document> GetNestedDocuments(IndexSearcher searcher, int parentDocId)
{
    List<Lucene.Net.Documents.Document> documents = new List<Lucene.Net.Documents.Document>();

    int subIndex = ReaderUtil.SubIndex(parentDocId, searcher.IndexReader.Leaves);
    var leaf = searcher.IndexReader.Leaves[subIndex];

    if (parentDocId > leaf.DocBase)
    {
        for (var childDocIndex = leaf.DocBase; childDocIndex < parentDocId; childDocIndex++)
        {
            var childDoc = searcher.Doc(childDocIndex);
            documents.Add(childDoc);
        }
    }

    return documents;
}
```